# ArrayList throws java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have this code

```
   List<Item> listOfItems = itemsPlanning.get(editText.getTag());  
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.size(); i++) {                                
       Item item = listOfItems.get(i);              
   }
```

First and second lines works as expected, but the third throws exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to Item
```

`listOfItems` is a list containing one element(in first case, seen from debug mode), `itemsPlanning` is a `HashMap` with values of type `List<Item>`, and the keys are tags for a list of edittexts.

Thank you.

Comment: It appears that, contrary to what you think, `itemsPlanning.get(editText.getTag())` returns a `List<List<Item>>` and not a `List<Item>`. And the type of `itemsPlanning` is probably a raw `Map`, or the compiler would have caught that error for you.

Comment: You are right. Even if the definition for itemsPlanning is HashMap<Date, List<Item>>, i don't know how this contains something else... Thank you sir !! Have a great day.